# How do i establish two way encrypted server-client-connection in python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, rsa

For a project, I need a server and a client. Not a problem so far. The difficulty is for me, that the connection must be encrypted since sensible information will be sent. You could use RSA encryption. I just don't know yet how to exchange the keys so nobody could intercept them or get any other chance to reach them.
Since I don't know, how to do it in general, I did not try anything so far.

Comment: For a key exchange, diffie-helman is worth looking at, as is elliptic-curve-diffie-helman. However, setting up a TLS connection would be a good idea because it uses a well established protocol that is widely used

Comment: thank you! Could you write it as an answer with a particular code example/scheme? It would be great.

Comment: please make sure to upvote my post if you think it can be helpful for other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a TLS connection implementation in Python. All key exchanging and encrypting data is done within the protocol.

```
import socket
import ssl

def main():
  #Define Host Name And Port (Port 443 Is Typical Encrypted Web Connection Port)
  host_name = "www.google.com"
  host_port = 443

  #Create Unencrypted Connection And Then Encrypted It By Wrapping It
  unencrypted_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  unencrypted_socket.settimeout(10)
  encrypted_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(unencrypted_socket,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1) #Optional Ciphers Spec Parameter Too

  #Connect To The Host, Send Data And Wait To Recieve Data
  encrypted_socket.connect((host_name,host_port))
  encrypted_socket.send(b"Hello")
  response = encrypted_socket.recv(512)

  #Close The Connection
  encrypted_socket.close()

main()
```

Note: I am using Python 3.6, and I think that a newer version of TLS is available to use as of Python 3.7.

Comment: On serverside everything works out the same, except you don't connnect to a server but bind to an address etc., as you would normally when working with sockets, right?

Comment: Yes, it has to bind, listen and then accept an incoming connection. Each incoming connection must be wrapped with TLS on serverside